# Setting https default for axios ajax requests

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I am trying to perform an ajax request with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) but I need it to be an https request.

```
axios.get('/relativeurl')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I can't seem to be able to find any configuration options for https. Obviously the easy way would be to use an absolute path and just set https in front of it but this is used on multiple domains.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to default the ajax requests from axios with the https protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through `axios.create`

```
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.location.origin
});

instance.post() //etc
```

Also, u can directly modify `axios` global configuration. Just add your configuration right after the `import axios from 'axios';`

```
window.axios = axios; //seems like it doesn't work without making a global object
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin;
```